# Trouble getting nav links to stay in the top left and be fixed there

Tags: html, css

I have my nav links but they keep showing up in the bottom of the box but I need them to be in the top left. I have tried a fixed position but not sure what is wrong. I will attach the CSS, let me know if you will need the HTML as I am a beginner and not sure what is needed.

Here is the CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.col-container {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}
.col {
display: table-cell;
padding: 20px;
}

header {background-image: url(stars.jpg);
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white; }

h1 {font-size: 2em;}

nav {
padding: 20px;
float: left;
width: 160px;
background-color: #1d9c81;
  }

nav a {text-decoration: none;}
nav a:link {color: #FFFFFF;}
nav a:hover {background-color: #49239b;}

nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;}
  
article {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #ffffffe2;}

  
/* Clear floats after the columns */
section::after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;}
  
footer {
background-color: darkblue;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
height: 60px;
color: white; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can attach the html it would be easier to help you.
Based on what you say you can use a class for your nav, or your nav element with the code below in css

```
nav {
position : fixed ;
top : 0px ;
left : 0px ;
z-index : 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be fixed, you can solve it by putting `position : fixed ;` in the target.

If you want it to be fixed at the top, give it `top:0`. If you want it to be fixed at the bottom, give it `bottom:0`. Left and right can be written as `left` and `right` as well, and CSS units such as `10px` can be used instead of the previously written value of 0.

For example, if you want to pin `.navs` to the top, write the code as follows

```css
.navs{
  position : fixed;
  top : 0px;
}
```

You can also use the `z-index` to raise the target if it is below it. For example, to put `.navs` at the top, use `z-index:999;`.